# Prevent Data from changing in a Access table

Tags: ms-access, field, datafield

I'm trying to have a table only be updated by queries in the access database and prevent the ability for anyone to update the data in the tables physically. They will be able to still open the table and look at the data though.

Is this possible and not use the access web app?

Comment: Short answer is No. If the users have access to the database in read-write mode, they can update the tables. Access has no web app, but you can build your own.

Comment: Or split the db and don't give access to the tables but create forms that look like tables.